# Resharper and VS, shortcuts changes automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

Here is my problem:

After a fresh installation of Resharper, all my shorcuts are perfectly fine. Then, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, but suddently all my shortcuts get messed up. Shortcuts change and sometime just disapear. The scheme may change several times.

When I reset my VS settings and then re-apply the resharper scheme, everything work fine for a while and then everything change again.

I use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3 and Resharper Ultimate 2017.1.2

Is there a shortcut to change shortcuts with Resharper or Visual Studio I may not be aware of??

Thanks!

Comment: Did you login to Visual Studio account?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an account

Comment: Are you using multiple VS instances on several computers?

Comment: That was it! Unchecking "Synchronize settings across devices when signed into Visual Studio" solved my problem. Thx!

Comment: You're welcome. I have even better idea how to fix it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Visual Studio account is used, settings are syncronized across all computers where you logged in. In-sync settings are listed here:
[Synchronized Settings in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135229.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So, I guess this is the problem.

Quick way: disable sync in `Options -> Environment -> Synchronized Settings`.

*Right way*: make the sync to work correctly.

1. Close all VS instances across all your computers.
2. Open single VS instance. Make sure you've signed in.
3. Setup the settings and make a backup (`Tools -> Import and Export Settings...`).
4. After a while, close VS. Probably it should trigger the syncronization.
5. Open second VS instance and ensure you have correct
   and latest settings there.